# What word or phrase can I use in this situation?

Tags: phrases, expressions

What would I use to indicate "continue in that likeness"?

For instance, let's say I'm correcting someone on conciseness. I tell the person to avoid sentences like "the thoughts of jake" and the "brass tacks of society" to favor ones like "jake's thoughts" and "society's brass tacks" instead. What word would I then use after these to indicate that they should apply this reasoning to other situations where they may see the patterns?

Comment: You need to be clear: are you asking about the genitive 's' v. of + NP, or  do you mean circumlocution in general, e.g. calling a spade "a hand-held digging implement"? (And don't say "both" - please be specific.)

Comment: NB. _Jake_ is a proper name and should begin with a capital letter. The expression _society's brass tacks_ is not at all idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

You could say

> Keep it as *a general rule*.

> General rule:
>
> - a usual way of doing things ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/general%20rule#:%7E:text=noun,usual%20way%20of%20doing%20things))

It implies that you should follow this pattern in other circumstances, but also that it is not absolute, that one can allow for some exception.

Answer (score 0):

You say...

> *Instead of "the thoughts of Jake", use "Jake's thoughts",*
> *Instead of the "brass tacks of society", use "society's brass tacks"<sup>1</sup>,*
> ***and so on***

It even gets its own dedicated dictionary definition...

> **and so on**   adverb [<sup><sub>(vocabulary.com)</sub></sup>](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/and%20so%20on)
> *continuing in the same way*

---

<sup>1</sup> Except don't say this one with ***of*** OR with the Saxon genitive, because *neither* are idiomatic.

Comment: Hmm. How can some anonymous downvoter think my ***continuing in the same way*** doesn't mean the same as OP's requested  ***continue in that likeness***?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe they have been and so on throughout their user activity.

Comment: Or maybe it somehow reflects the fact that my answer comes at things rather differently to @fev's. Which is a sort of "external" description of the nature of the advice given by OP, whereas mine is more of an "internal" expression that OP might use ***within*** his advice-giving utterances.